# Variable as Where clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a stored procedure that has many possible where clauses. What I have for the stored procedure now returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'" as an error.

```
Select @SQL = 'SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
WHERE ' + @where

Exec(@SQL)
```

@Where would something like

```
'Table1.Col1 = 'Apples' OR Table1.Col1 = 'BANNANAS' OR Table2.Col2 = 'CHOCOLATE''
```

Edit:
After messing around with it with all the suggestions I was able to get it to run without an error. Now it wont return any results though.

Comment: So What is the problem?

Comment: Try escaping the single quotes for values.

Comment: What's the syntax error?  run `SELECT @SQL` to find exactly what your query is, and then run that standalone, what happens?

Comment: Tom: Running it as that still returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'." so I am guessing that the query is wrong to start with and not just the @Where.

Comment: Read this before proceeding with your plan: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases

Comment: Well, comment out EXEC(@Sql) while you're running SELECT @Sql.

Comment: sql injection... sql injection everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could your issue be that you need to double quote all of your literals?

```
'Table1.Col1 = ''Apples'' OR Table1.Col1 = ''BANNANAS'' OR Table2.Col2 = ''CHOCOLATE'''
```

Comment: Tried that and still got "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."

Comment: Please execute "select @SQL" and post the results to your question (edit your question).

Comment: Seems to work here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3093f/3 -- note, this doesn't return anything because I don't have Chocolate, Bananas, or Apples as values, but it works.  Check your syntax again.  Does `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1` return?  Maybe you're not using the correct schema

Comment: Guess it really was the quotes issue in the end. Got it working based off the sqlfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Use char(39) as quotes.

```
'Table1.Col1 = '+char(39)+Apples+char(39)+' OR Table1.Col1 = '+ Char(39)+BANNANAS+char(39)+' OR Table2.Col2 = '+char(39)+CHOCOLATE+char(39)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution.

It's not "dynamic sql", but it is flexible and "cleaner" IMHO.

```
Use Northwind
GO

declare @holder table (ProductName nvarchar(40))


Insert into @holder (ProductName )
select
'Chai' union all select 'Chang' union all select 'Aniseed Syrup'

SELECT 
        [ProductID]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SupplierID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[QuantityPerUnit]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[UnitsInStock]
      ,[UnitsOnOrder]
      ,[ReorderLevel]
      ,[Discontinued]
FROM 
  [dbo].[Products] prod
  where
        exists (select null from @holder innerH where innerH.ProductName = prod.ProductName)


declare @holderCOUNT int
select @holderCOUNT = count(*) from @holder


SELECT 
        [ProductID]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SupplierID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[QuantityPerUnit]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[UnitsInStock]
      ,[UnitsOnOrder]
      ,[ReorderLevel]
      ,[Discontinued]
FROM 
  [dbo].[Products] prod
  where
    ( @holderCOUNT = 0 OR ( exists (select null from @holder innerH where innerH.ProductName = prod.ProductName)  ))

delete from @holder
select @holderCOUNT = count(*) from @holder

SELECT 
        [ProductID]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SupplierID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[QuantityPerUnit]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[UnitsInStock]
      ,[UnitsOnOrder]
      ,[ReorderLevel]
      ,[Discontinued]
FROM 
  [dbo].[Products] prod
  where
    ( @holderCOUNT = 0 OR ( exists (select null from @holder innerH where innerH.ProductName = `enter code here`prod.ProductName)  ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just guessing, but should you use a different name for the variable "@Where".

Btw) it's not a good practice to make such kind of building queries from strings. Performance, security and all these kind of problems.

André

Comment: This would probably be better served as a comment to the OP, not a standalone answer, IMHO.  I did not downvote you, I am trying to explain why some may have done so.